# Sony STR DN1030 2nd volume control using a second Vr Encoder

Tags: voltage-regulator, components, power-electronics, encoder, receiver

First off, I am very, very new to any electronic physics/engineering.
Here's my problem:

I want a second remote volume control for my receiver that is wired to my desk. (I have already managed to make the standby switch work) There are three pins on the current VR encoder in the unit (Part #: 141872541 on Sears Parts Direct or http://www.searspartsdirect.com/sony-audio-equipment-parts/141872541/0057/528/model-STRDN1030/0996/0311300.html).

Is it possible to buy a replacement VR encoder and just solder the second encoder, via a usb 3.0 wire, directly to the current contacts so there are two encoders connected to each terminal on the board? (I'm thinking no)

The second solution I was thinking of was having the output of the first encoder be the input of the second encoder, and run the output of the second encoder back into the board.

Also would the product below work as a replacement for the encoder, or should I just pay the premium for the genuine part? (I was thinking no because my understanding is that an encoder changes binary code and this changes voltages)

*"RadioShack® 100K Dual-Ganged Stereo Volume Control"(100K dual-ganged stereo volume control with audio taper. Double potentiometer 40% loudness tap)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dual ganged stereo volume control with audio taper is a potentiometer. That is "a variable resistor". Actually a dual variable resistor! This is an analog component.

The other product, VR Encoder, is a low resolution digital encoder that can create two signals that are digital in nature that are 90 degrees out of phase with each other. This is often called a quadrature encoder too.

The two components are completely different from each other and can never be used directly in place of each other.

You will not be able to parallel up the quadrature contacts of two of the VR Encoders because 75% of the time the one of the internal contacts that create the switch closures to produce the Chan A and Chan B outputs will be closed. The parallel encoder channel to one that was closed would not work.

You may be better off making some type of wireless remote robotic mechanism that used a rubber belt to turn the actual knob on the stereo receiver.